# Powershell script error when output Array inside if statement

Tags: powershell

I am running following script in powershell script and getting error.

```
$queues = Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_msmq_MSMQQueue
```

$list = $queues | ft -property Name,MessagesInQueue

for ( $i = 0; $i -lt 6; $i++ ) 
{

if ($i -gt 2) 
    {

```
$list[$i] 

}
```

}

**Error:** 
out-lineoutput : The object of type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData" is not valid or not in the correct sequence. This is likely caused by a 
user-specified "format-*" command which is conflicting with the default formatting.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [out-lineoutput], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConsoleLineOutputOutOfSequencePacket,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutLineOutputCommand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are simply trying to skip the headers for your data when displayed with `Format-Table` (or `FT` for short as you used). To do that just use the `-HideTableHeaders` switch on your FT command, and don't capture it in a variable.

```
$queues = Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_msmq_MSMQQueue
$queues | ft -property Name,MessagesInQueue -HideTableHeaders
```

For that matter, you should only use `Format-Table` or any of the `Format-` commands to display text, not to store in a variable. If you only want the first 4 entries you would pipe to a `Select` command before the `FT` like:

```
$queues = Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_msmq_MSMQQueue
$queues | Select -First 4 | ft -property Name,MessagesInQueue -HideTableHeaders
```